# How to loop through String[], convert to class, get class field

Tags: java

I'm trying to loop through a String array in my Object class "Cog" constructor, shown here

```
public Cog(int lvl, String inputName, Entity eInput, NPC inputNPC) {
    level = lvl;
    fullName = inputName;
    npc = inputNPC;
    e = (LivingEntity) eInput;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        if (fullName.contains(CogsController.cogSuits[i])) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (fullName.contains(CogsController.cogNames[i][j])) cogName = CogsController.cogNames[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Using the public static variables shown here:

```
public static String[] cogSuits = {"Bossbot", "Lawbot", "Cashbot", "Sellbot"};
public static String[] bbCogNames = {"Flunky", "Pencil Pusher"};
public static String[] lbCogNames = {"Temp1", "Temp2"};
public static String[] cbCogNames = {"Temp3", "Temp4"};
public static String[] sbCogNames = {"Temp5", "Temp6"};
public static String[] cogNames[] = {bbCogNames, lbCogNames, cbCogNames, sbCogNames};
```

Then trying to set the variable in the Cog class shown here

```
int[] storedAttacks[][] = {};
```

To the values stored in, for example, the "Flunky" class, shown here

```
public class Flunky {
public static int[][] PoundKey = {
        {30, 35, 40, 45, 50},
        {2, 2, 3, 4, 6},
        {75, 75, 80, 80, 90}
};
public static int[][] Shred = {
        {10, 15, 20, 25, 30},
        {3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
        {50, 5, 60, 65, 70}
};
public static int[] attacks[][] = {PoundKey, Shred};
}
```

I'm currently, in a method to load the attacks in the Cog Class, trying to convert "cogName" to an class object to then pull the values stored in the class of the same name. I'm stuck there and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to put `PoundKey`, `Shred` etc into a map like the following and access the `int[][]` values using `String` keys:

```
public class Flunky {

    public static Map<String, int[][]> myMap = new HashMap<>() {{
       myMap.put("PoundKey", new int[][] {
               {30, 35, 40, 45, 50},
               {2, 2, 3, 4, 6},
               {75, 75, 80, 80, 90}
       });

       myMap.put("Shred", new int[][] {
               {10, 15, 20, 25, 30},
               {3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
               {50, 5, 60, 65, 70}
       });
    }};


    public static int[] attacks[][] = {myMap.get("PoundKey"), myMap.get("Shred")};
}
```